# Saga: Difference Orechestrator & (Saga Execution Controller)Choreography

Tags: architecture, event-handling, saga

I am currently struggling to see the difference in implementing the Saga pattern: 
From theory, I understand the difference between orchestration and choreography. Looking at implementations of choreography, I find the usage of a 'Saga Execution Controller' (SEC). The SEC is meant to track the status of the distributed transaction. From my point of view, the SEC is also an orchestrator as it manages compensations. 
So what is the difference between an orchestrator and an SEC?